# Access Wordpress PHP Variables within Plugin JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

edit: I'm now wondering how I can access post ID from within plugin (outside of loop). If I try to get the post id, it returns 0.

How does one access a specific page's PHP variables within a plugin JS file?

I originally had the JS in the page template file but have moved it to a plugin. Now I am unsure how to access that page's PHP variables. Maybe move the PHP logic to a plugin function?

**content-course.php (JS)**

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$course_id = $post->ID;
$vimeo_progress = 0;
$vimeo_seconds = 0;

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    // Run WP query to retrieve user progress
    $row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = %d AND course_id = %d;", $user_id, $course_id) );

    if ($row) {
        $vimeo_seconds = $row->seconds_played;
        $vimeo_progress = $row->progress_percent;
    }
}
?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var progress = <?php echo $vimeo_progress; ?>;
var seconds = <?php echo $vimeo_seconds; ?>;
var userProgress = <?php echo $vimeo_seconds; ?>; //example user data retrieved
var lastUpdateProgress = <?php echo $vimeo_progress; ?>;
var videoUrl;
var courseID = <?php echo $course_id; ?>;
</script>
```

How would the JS script be able to access the PHP variables if moved to the plugin? Do I need to move the PHP above the script to a plugin function.. because then I am not sure how it would pass the data to the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress have a classified function for the job
wp_localize_script()

Take a look. It's very easy to do.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: I would i get the course_id from within the plugin to use in wp_localize_script()? Right now it seems to always return 0.  http://gist.github.com/gil--/bfdece5f0053aa0f02f9

Comment: You should pass the $course_id variable's value to your js file through wp_localize_script as an associative array. Isn't it working?